# Flex: should I define components path in each module or just main application mxml?

Tags: apache-flex, module

I'm implementing a Flex application with several modules.
I'm reusing the same component in all these modules.

I was wondering if I'm correctly importing it in each mxml module definition:

```
   ... xmlns:hillelcoren="com.hillelcoren.components.*" ...
```

Should I import it only once, in the main application mxml instead ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to import the shared component into each.  Flex will compile a copy of your shared component into each module's SWF.  If you want to truly share the component you will have to move it to it's own module and have each module in turn depend on that one.